# How do I find what program initiated a download using wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I have a packet capture and I'm trying to find out which program a download was made with, where would I go in the packet to find this information?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for answers within the packet, you may want to look at which port the download was done through. That could give you more information, and faster

Comment: Could you please explain how the port allows me to find the program and why it gives me more information faster?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know the destination ip address from where the file is downloaded. If it's something that you can catch while it's happening or you can trigger it then you could use `netstat` to determine the PID of the program that is handling that socket after filtering the netstat output based on the destination ip address.
Then you could use `ps` on Linux or TaskManager on Windows to know which program has that PID.
On windows: [How to determine which program uses or blocks specific transmission control protocol ports in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/281336)

Alternative if the packet capture it's all you got and it's not a recurring event then if the download was done via HTTP you could check the headers of the HTTP request for info about the client in the `User-Agent` header.

Hope it helps.